# why the pipe doesn't work on `python -V/java -version` etc?

Tags: pipe, file-descriptor

Today I found something interesting. Please check my test first:

```
kent$  ruby --version
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

kent$  ruby --version|sed 's/ruby/----/'
---- 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

kent$  python -V                                                                                                  
Python 2.7.11

kent$  python -V|sed 's/Python/----/'   
Python 2.7.11

kent$  java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

kent$  java -version|sed 's/[jJ]ava/----/'
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

As you see above, I want to do text processing on the output of a command (output of checking version info of python, ruby, java)

The `sed` is simple enough, but only `ruby --version` worked. I tried replacing `sed` with other linux common commands, like `awk, grep...` resulted same.

I have tested with:

- tty + bash/zsh
- Urxvt + bash/zsh
- Xfce Terminal + bash/zsh

Testing results are same.

I also tested `java -h| sed 's/[jJ]ava/----/'`, it doesn't work either. However `python -h|sed 's/PYTHON/----/'` worked.

I thought those outputs are stdout, and after the `pipe`, it would be `stdin` and should be accepted by the following commands as input... but it seems that I am wrong.

Can someone please explain why does it happen?

If it is necessary, some env./version info of my testing machine:

- bash 4.3.42
- zsh 5.2
- Linux 4.2.5-1 (Archlinux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, java is printing its output on `stderr`. For example:

```
$ java -version > /dev/null
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
```

So, if you want to send it over a pipe on stdin:

```
$ java -version 2>&1 |sed 's/[jJ]ava/----/'
---- version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: thanx! you are right! I simply thought those info should be stdout. Just now did tests,  `stderr (fd2)` : `python -v, java -version, java -h` however `stdout (fd1)`: `ruby -*, python -h` ... it is kind of mess...